# kAudioDevicePropertyBufferFrameSizeRange returns { 0, 0}

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, hal

I'm trying to use CoreAudio to get the expected buffer sizes on hardware for MacOS. My current strategy for this is based on [this technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2321/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013499-CH1-THE_I_O_BUFFER_SIZE).

The code is implemented as follows:

```
        AudioObjectID DeviceAudioObjectID;
        AudioObjectPropertyAddress DevicePropertyAddress;
        UInt32 AudioDeviceQuerySize;
        OSStatus Status;
        int32 BufferSize = 0;

        //Get Audio Device ID
        DevicePropertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice;
        DevicePropertyAddress.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
        DevicePropertyAddress.mElement = 0;
        AudioDeviceQuerySize = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
        Status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &DevicePropertyAddress, 0, nullptr, &AudioDeviceQuerySize, &DeviceAudioObjectID);

        DevicePropertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyBufferFrameSizeRange;
        DevicePropertyAddress.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
        DevicePropertyAddress.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
        AudioValueRange BufferSizeRange = { 0, 0 };
        AudioDeviceQuerySize = sizeof(AudioValueRange);
        Status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(DeviceAudioObjectID, &DevicePropertyAddress, 0, nullptr, &AudioDeviceQuerySize, &BufferSizeRange);
```

On my current Mac (a Mac Pro running Sierra), The final call to `AudioObjectGetPropertyData` here results in `BufferSizeRange` being explicitly set to `{ 0, 0 }`. The call returns with `0`, indicating success.

How do I properly query the range of possible buffer sizes supported by the hardware?

Comment: Do you get a valid `AudioObjectID` returned from your first `AudioObjectGetPropertyData()` call? And does that id match one of the devices when invoking `system_profiler SPAudioDataType` in the terminal? I would go looking for the kind of default output device the system has currently set.

Comment: This was the issue. AudioObjectID was not being set to a valid ID on the device. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where's your problem. I've tried your code on my MacBook with OS X Sierra and it worked well. When I've checked the result stored in BufferSizeRange I got mMinimum = 14 and mMaximum = 4096.

I've just changed the wrong initialization of BufferSize (you wrote int32 that doesn't exist as variable), I've substitute nullptr with NULL and set DevicePropertyAddress.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster when you're asking for knowing who's the default output device.

However I recommend you to ask directly to CoreAudio the size of the property you want to know with AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize and to check with an if statement functions's return value.